# Adding formula to a column of a table using xlwings

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I am trying to automate an Excel sheet using Xlwings that has 2 tables. I want to add a formula to the performance column of both tables such that If I input new data into the table it automatically uses the formula to calculate I was able to do it for range but not for tables.

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book() 
column_name = 'Sales'
formula = '=IF([@[Sales]]<40000, "Bad", IF(AND([@[Sales]]>=40000, [@[Sales]]<=75000), "Neutral", "Good"))'

for table_name in ['Table1', 'Table2'`your text`]:
    wb.sheets[0][f'{table_name}[{column_name}]'].formula = formula
```

Comment: You haven't told us anything about the specific problem you're having with the code you posted though...

Answer (score 0):

```py
import xlwings as xw
# modify as needed
file_path = r'd:\temp\test.xlsx'
try:
    # get opened workbook by its fullname
    wb = xw.books[file_path]
except:
    # If not found, open the workbook
    wb = xw.Book(file_path)
# Set the column name, modify as needed
column_name = 'flag'
formula = '=IF([@[Sales]]<40000, "Bad", IF(AND([@[Sales]]>=40000, [@[Sales]]<=75000), "Neutral", "Good"))'
# Iterate through table names and set the formula in each table
for table_name in ['Table1', 'Table2']:
    table_range = wb.sheets[0][f'{table_name}[{column_name}]']
    table_range.formula = formula
# Save the workbook
wb.save(file_path)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you state "*If I input new data into the table it automatically uses the formula to calculate*" suggests you mean that when you add a new value to the Sales column then the formula is automagically added in the performance column?
For this to work in Excel you need to add the formula first then convert to a table.

The following code shows an example;
**Code Sample**
The code creates a new workbook and adds data for Sales and Performance into one row with a header row.
It then converts this data into a table called 'Sales'.

**Testing Operation**
To test we add a new value to the next row in the table. We are updating the Sales column only with **no** formula added to the corresponding performance column.
Therefore we update cell 'A3' with the value 90,000 only.

When the Workbook is opened in Excel, in Sheet 'Sales' we see the table has two rows of data;
The original Sales value 10,000 used to create the table with its corresponding formula written as part of the original data.
The new row, Sales value 90,000 added after the Table was created. This row should also have the formula applied. This was done automagically by Excel when added by Xlwings.
Now if you add another value to the table, row 4, the formula will automagically be added to that row as well and so on.

```
from time import sleep
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

filename = 'newfile1.xlsx'
sheetname = 'Sales'

formula = f'=IF({sheetname}!$A2<40000,"Bad",IF(AND({sheetname}!$A2>=40000,{sheetname}!$A2<=75000),"Neutral","Good"))'

### Data for initial table, value and formula
### Using Pandas as a convenient method to add some test data to the sheet
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Sales": [10000],
    "Performance": [formula],
})

with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book()
    ws = wb.sheets.active
    ws.name = sheetname

    ### Add data to the sheet
    ws["A1"].options(pd.DataFrame, header=True, index=False).value = df
    ### Convert the data into a table
    table = ws.tables.add(source=ws['A1'].expand(), name='Sales')

    ### Test data input by adding a new Sales value to the next free row (row 3, cell A3) ###
    print("Test formula updating!")
    ###
    sleep(2)
    val = 90000
    print(f'Now add a new value {val} to the next row of the table (Cell A3)')
    ws['A3'].value = val

    ### Save workbook
    wb.save(filename)
```

**Example screenshot**
The Sales value 90,000 is added by Xlwings
The Sales value 50,000 is added manually
For both Sales values the Performance formula is automatically applied by Excel.

[image: Example sheet]